# C# DataGridView columns 1 compare with columns 1 like this image

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, ado.net

I want to make a comparison:

```
if(already employee id == last cell employee)
{
    MessagBox.show(Your Value is duplicated)
}
```

[As shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz6TA.png)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please clearify you question in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one point you into the right direction:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Data of inserted value
    var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    var colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    var insertedValue = (dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex].Value ?? "").ToString();

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        // If current cell == insertedValue but not the same row
        if((row.Cells["ColumnID"].Value ?? "").ToString() == insertedValue && row.Index != rowIndex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Value is duplicated");
        }
    }
}
```

**Linq is also possible:**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var insertedValue = (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value ?? "").ToString();

    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where
        (   
            x => (x.Cells["ColumnID"].Value ?? "").ToString() == insertedValue
            && x.Index != e.RowIndex
        )
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => MessageBox.Show("Your Value is duplicated"));
}
```

[image]

Notice that this one wont delete the inserted value. So if you AGAIN insert the same value, the `MessageBox` will raise 2 times.

Comment: @NumanKibria Glad I could help. Consider marking it as solution then (hook right under the voting-buttons).

Comment: can we make it as cell are selected till duplicate EmployeeID remove or deleted from inserted cell or new different value Entered

Comment: @NumanKibria You could clear the ID like this `dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = String.Empty;`. I would then change the text of the `MessageBox` to `No dublicates allowed. Please insert a unique value!`.